# Get dates when NYSE was closed in R, holidays and unplanned closures

Tags: r, quantmod

I know there already solutions that provide the holiday calendars for various Stock Exchanges (such as `timeDate::holidayNYSE`), however I am also interested in dates where the NYSE was closed on non-planned holidays.  For example, the NYSE was closed 9/11/2001 - 9/14/2001 as well as 10/29/2012 - 10/30/2012.

This code gives me the holidays.

```
library(timeDate)
holidayNYSE(2012)
```

Does a similar function exists (in `timeDate` or another package) that would give me dates closure dates such as 9/11/2001 - 9/14/2001 and 10/29/2012 - 10/30/2012?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RQuantLib:

```
R> library(RQuantLib)
R> library(anytime)  # for anydate
R> holidayList(calendar="UnitedStates/NYSE", 
+              from=anydate("2001-09-01"), to=anydate("2001-09-30"))
[1] "2001-09-03" "2001-09-11" "2001-09-12" "2001-09-13" "2001-09-14"
R> 
R> holidayList(calendar="UnitedStates/NYSE", 
+              from=anydate("2012-10-01"), to=anydate("2012-10-31"))
[1] "2012-10-29" "2012-10-30"
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a `csv` file with special NYSE closings (inter & intraday, not regular NYSE holidays, there are more than 370 special closings) from 1885 to 2011. Hope this helps ! 
[download file](http://d.elmagoasset.com/ojyIbk)